# hide dataset by default using Chart.js and a custom script

Tags: javascript, wordpress, chart.js

I'm using wpDataTables plugin on my WordPress website to draw some tables and charts. The charts are rendered using Chart.js. The developers of the plugin created a custom script to control some more aspects of Chart.js than the plugin can handle out of the box.

That's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    if( typeof wpDataChartsCallbacks == 'undefined' ){ wpDataChartsCallbacks = {}; }
    wpDataChartsCallbacks[39] = function(obj){
        obj.options.options.scales.yAxes[0].display = false;
        obj.options.options.scales.xAxes[0].display = false;
    }
});
</script>
```

In this example it hides the axes of the chart with the ID 39. I need to change the above script to hide a specific dataset (line in the chart) by default. My chart ID is 2 and I want to hide the dataset labelled "SPM".

You can take a look at the table and chart how it currently looks like here (it's a weapon overview of a game, so please do not wonder): https://mydivision.net/the-division-waffen/

The first chart has all datasets visible by default:
[image]
I want it to look like this by default ("SPM" line hidden):
[image]

Can anyone please assist how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    if( typeof wpDataChartsCallbacks == 'undefined' ){ wpDataChartsCallbacks = {}; }
    wpDataChartsCallbacks[2] = function(obj){
        obj.options.data.datasets[5].hidden = true;
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is taken from the [ChartJS GitHub](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3150).

You set the new value and then use the ChartJS API to update the chart to hide the ones you have toggled off. If you wanted to toggle them again you just do the reverse.

```
//Hide
chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden=true;
chart.update();

//Show
chart.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden=false;
chart.update();
```

Here's an example in [JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gt5crc82/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I integrate this into the script posted above?

Comment: It depends on what one of the labels you are trying to hide. Without testing properly, try obj.getDatasetMeta(1).hidden=true; then change the "1" to the label to hide.

Comment: I found out that it's label 5 I want to hide by default. So I added the line to the script and replaced 1 by 5. But then the chart is not loading at all. :(

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    if( typeof wpDataChartsCallbacks == 'undefined' ){ wpDataChartsCallbacks = {}; }
    wpDataChartsCallbacks[2] = function(obj){

 obj.getDatasetMeta(5).hidden = true;

    }
});
</script>

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. Can you show the code for generating the whole chart you are trying to affect, not just the function that hides the label. I can't debug what is wrong without seeing your code.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to add `hidden:true` to your `datasets`

```
{
  label: "something",
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  data: data,
  hidden: true
}
```